# What is lenny8 in the PHP version string?

Tags: php

my PHP install identifies as **PHP Version 5.2.6-1+lenny8**

I know what **PHP Version 5.2.6-1** is obviously, but what is **lenny8** ?

Searching around was useless

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a version of [Debian](http://www.debian.org/releases/lenny/) linux.  That means that your PHP package was built specifically for that version of Debian.

Answer (score 5):

Lenny is codename of debian (5.0) version. You are probably running debian, and the PHP installed is from debian repository packages

Comment: Thank you so much! This is the hosting server, so I dont know what is the exact Linux distro. I could never tell it was related to the OS